# UIWindow --- What is the difference between them

Tags: ios, show

idapp = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UIWindow *widow = [app window];

NSArray *windowsArray = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
   UIWindow *showWindow = [windowsArray lastObject];

What is the difference between them ？？

Comment: what the issue here ?

Comment: Prompt box may show not to come out

Comment: what is the CHDLastHUD ?

Comment: static MBProgressHUD *CHDLastHUD;
static NSInteger animationDuration = 1.f;
static NSInteger HUD_width = 170.f;
static NSInteger HUD_height = 125.f;

Comment: if (CHDLastHUD) {
        [CHDLastHUD hideAnimated:NO];
    } remove this condition ;

Comment: thanks but  If pop two at the same time, the disappearance of the first came out.So you can't delete it

Comment: then you need to put condition . if CHDLastHUD is not hidden and if hidden then show again .

Comment: you need to initialize CHDLastHUD only once. second time you need to play with hide and show property of that view.

Comment: is solved your problem ?

Comment: No, I think should be the problem of the window, because I have more than one place in the program, launched interface is using a UIWindow.Prompt box does not appear probability is very low.So it's hard for me to locate to the problem

Comment: can i give my code for hide and show MBProcess HUD ?

Comment: Of course, you can

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

**For Show**

```
+ (MBProgressHUD *)showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
    hud.label.text = title;
    return hud;
}
```

**For Hide**

```
  + (void)dismissGlobalHUD {
        UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:window animated:YES];
    }
```